# Ionic - Drag element from one view to another

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm using the Ionic Framework to build a hybrid app and its heavily dependant on drag and drop features. Using the 'sidemenu' template I have created one main view, and two side menus.

The main view will use the [Ionic Calendar](https://github.com/twinssbc/Ionic-Calendar) to display data. The two side menus will be used as views where data will initial be stored in list form. I need to be able to drag elements from side menu and into the main screen, where they can then be dropped on the calendar.

All the events work perfect when in calendar view (ie. onClickItem, onClickTime, etc). The drag and drop call backs work fine too, when remaining in the side menu display area. However, when I try to drag the element out of the side menu area and into the calendar, only the onDragStop event is recognized and not the onClickTime event from the calendar.

I realize I'm trying to fuse a few things together here in a not so usual way. I can't even find anyone else making posts about the same thing. Maybe I'm making the wrong searches.

Any help, advice, or direction would be appreciated.

Comment: can you add your code or some front end playground examples (jsfiddle,codepen etc....)